# Camera preview opens up the native camera instead of taking photo

Tags: flutter

So I am building a camera app, and currently, when I click the button in my bottom navigation, it opens the camera preview which has a button to take the photo.

When that button is clicked, it then goes and opens the native camera, instead of taking a photo.

I believe I have pinpointed the error here:

```
  onPressed: () {
                _openGallery();
                Navigator.pop(context);
```

within this block

```
Widget _cameraControlWidget(context) {
    return Expanded(
      child: Align(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          children: <Widget>[
            FloatingActionButton(
              child: Icon(
                Icons.camera,
                color: Colors.black,
              ),
              backgroundColor: Colors.white,
              onPressed: () {
                _openGallery();
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Is this correct? How can I rectify so that the 'camera preview' takes the photo, and not the native camera?

Here is the full page code:

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:camera/camera.dart';

class Camera extends StatefulWidget {
  Function setData;
  Camera({Key key, this.setData}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CameraScreenState createState() => _CameraScreenState();
}

class _CameraScreenState extends State<Camera> {
  CameraController controller;
  List cameras;
  int selectedCameraIndex;
  String imgPath;
  var image;

  Future _openGallery() async {
    image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
    if (widget.setData != null) {
      widget.setData(image);
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    availableCameras().then((availableCameras) {
      cameras = availableCameras;

      if (cameras.length > 0) {
        setState(() {
          selectedCameraIndex = 0;
        });
        _initCameraController(cameras[selectedCameraIndex]).then((void v) {});
      } else {
        print('No camera available');
      }
    }).catchError((err) {
      print('Error :${err.code}Error message : ${err.message}');
    });
  }

  Future _initCameraController(CameraDescription cameraDescription) async {
    if (controller != null) {
      await controller.dispose();
    }
    controller = CameraController(cameraDescription, ResolutionPreset.high);

    controller.addListener(() {
      if (mounted) {
        setState(() {});
      }

      if (controller.value.hasError) {
        print('Camera error ${controller.value.errorDescription}');
      }
    });

    try {
      await controller.initialize();
    } on CameraException catch (e) {
      _showCameraException(e);
    }
    if (mounted) {
      setState(() {});
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                flex: 1,
                child: _cameraPreviewWidget(),
              ),
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                child: Container(
                  height: 120,
                  width: double.infinity,
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      _cameraToggleRowWidget(),
                      _cameraControlWidget(context),
                      Spacer()
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  /// Display Camera preview.
  Widget _cameraPreviewWidget() {
    if (controller == null || !controller.value.isInitialized) {
      return const Text(
        'Loading',
        style: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.white,
          fontSize: 20.0,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
        ),
      );
    }

    return AspectRatio(
      aspectRatio: controller.value.aspectRatio,
      child: CameraPreview(controller),
    );
  }

  /// Display the control bar with buttons to take pictures
  Widget _cameraControlWidget(context) {
    return Expanded(
      child: Align(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          children: <Widget>[
            FloatingActionButton(
              child: Icon(
                Icons.camera,
                color: Colors.black,
              ),
              backgroundColor: Colors.white,
              onPressed: () {
                _openGallery();
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  /// Display a row of toggle to select the camera (or a message if no camera is available).
  Widget _cameraToggleRowWidget() {
    if (cameras == null || cameras.isEmpty) {
      return Spacer();
    }
    CameraDescription selectedCamera = cameras[selectedCameraIndex];
    CameraLensDirection lensDirection = selectedCamera.lensDirection;

    return Expanded(
      child: Align(
        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
        child: FlatButton.icon(
          onPressed: _onSwitchCamera,
          icon: Icon(
            _getCameraLensIcon(lensDirection),
            color: Colors.white,
            size: 24,
          ),
          label: Text(
            '${lensDirection.toString().substring(lensDirection.toString().indexOf('.') + 1).toUpperCase()}',
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  IconData _getCameraLensIcon(CameraLensDirection direction) {
    switch (direction) {
      case CameraLensDirection.back:
        return CupertinoIcons.switch_camera;
      case CameraLensDirection.front:
        return CupertinoIcons.switch_camera_solid;
      case CameraLensDirection.external:
        return Icons.camera;
      default:
        return Icons.device_unknown;
    }
  }

  void _showCameraException(CameraException e) {
    String errorText = 'Error:${e.code}\nError message : ${e.description}';
    print(errorText);
  }

  void _onSwitchCamera() {
    selectedCameraIndex =
        selectedCameraIndex < cameras.length - 1 ? selectedCameraIndex + 1 : 0;
    CameraDescription selectedCamera = cameras[selectedCameraIndex];
    _initCameraController(selectedCamera);
  }
}
```

Edit:

Here is my page which displays the photos:

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Homepage_1 extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<File> imageArray;
  Homepage_1({Key key, this.imageArray}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _Homepage_1State createState() => _Homepage_1State();
}

class _Homepage_1State extends State<Homepage_1> {
  var image;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        body: Column(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch, children: [
          Padding(
            padding:
                const EdgeInsets.only(top: 100, left: 40, right: 0, bottom: 0),
            child:
                Column(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start, children: [
              Text(
                'Stumble',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 60,
                  fontFamily: 'Avenir',
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                  margin:
                      EdgeInsets.only(top: 0, left: 0, right: 50, bottom: 0),
                  child: widget.imageArray.isEmpty
                      ? Column(children: [
                          Text(
                            'Yikes! You have no photos',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 19,
                              fontFamily: 'Avenir',
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                            ),
                          ),
                          Text(
                            'Click the circular button below', 
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 15,
                              fontFamily: 'Avenir',
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ])
                      : GridView.count(
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          crossAxisCount: 2,
                          crossAxisSpacing: 25,
                          mainAxisSpacing: 25,
                          childAspectRatio: (80 / 150),
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
                          children:
                              List.generate(widget.imageArray.length, (index) {
                            return ClipRRect(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                              child: Image.file(widget.imageArray[index],
                                  fit: BoxFit.fill),
                            );
                          })))
            ]),
          )
        ]));
  }
}
```

Comment: @SarveshDalvi I am already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you are using from this example

https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/plugins/picture-using-camera

Here is full code that I just tested

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:camera/camera.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  // Ensure that plugin services are initialized so that `availableCameras()`
  // can be called before `runApp()`
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  // Obtain a list of the available cameras on the device.
  final cameras = await availableCameras();

  // Get a specific camera from the list of available cameras.
  final firstCamera = cameras.first;

  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark(),
      home: TakePictureScreen(
        // Pass the appropriate camera to the TakePictureScreen widget.
        camera: firstCamera,
      ),
    ),
  );
}

// A screen that allows users to take a picture using a given camera.
class TakePictureScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final CameraDescription camera;

  const TakePictureScreen({
    Key key,
    @required this.camera,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  TakePictureScreenState createState() => TakePictureScreenState();
}

class TakePictureScreenState extends State<TakePictureScreen> {
  CameraController _controller;
  Future<void> _initializeControllerFuture;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // To display the current output from the Camera,
    // create a CameraController.
    _controller = CameraController(
      // Get a specific camera from the list of available cameras.
      widget.camera,
      // Define the resolution to use.
      ResolutionPreset.medium,
    );

    // Next, initialize the controller. This returns a Future.
    _initializeControllerFuture = _controller.initialize();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // Dispose of the controller when the widget is disposed.
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Take a picture')),
      // Wait until the controller is initialized before displaying the
      // camera preview. Use a FutureBuilder to display a loading spinner
      // until the controller has finished initializing.
      body: FutureBuilder<void>(
        future: _initializeControllerFuture,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
            // If the Future is complete, display the preview.
            return CameraPreview(_controller);
          } else {
            // Otherwise, display a loading indicator.
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          }
        },
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.camera_alt),
        // Provide an onPressed callback.
        onPressed: () async {
          // Take the Picture in a try / catch block. If anything goes wrong,
          // catch the error.
          try {
            // Ensure that the camera is initialized.
            await _initializeControllerFuture;

            // Attempt to take a picture and get the file `image`
            // where it was saved.
            final image = await _controller.takePicture();

            // If the picture was taken, display it on a new screen.
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => DisplayPictureScreen(
                  // Pass the automatically generated path to
                  // the DisplayPictureScreen widget.
                  imagePath: image?.path,
                ),
              ),
            );
          } catch (e) {
            // If an error occurs, log the error to the console.
            print(e);
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

// A widget that displays the picture taken by the user.
class DisplayPictureScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final String imagePath;

  const DisplayPictureScreen({Key key, this.imagePath}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Display the Picture')),
      // The image is stored as a file on the device. Use the `Image.file`
      // constructor with the given path to display the image.
      body: Image.file(File(imagePath)),
    );
  }
}
```

in pubspec.yaml

```
dependencies:
    flutter:
        sdk: flutter
    camera: ^0.8.1
    path_provider:
    path:
```

Comment: Just tried, and it does not integrate well (was not able to get it working) with the page that displays the photos. I have edited the post to include this code. Can you please take another look? I changed the page naming convention from your code to match mine accordingly, but did not work.

Comment: You asked ` How can I rectify so that the 'camera preview' takes the photo, and not the native camera?` and Thats the answer. Don't ask too many questions in one question. You should save pics somewhere then call them in GridView.